# Adding additional methods for a thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency

I thought I might be able to do it by trying something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[myNumThreads];
for (int i=0; i<myNumThreads; i++) {
    threads[i] = new Thread () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        <Code to do when running>
        }

        //CODE I TRIED TO ADD:
        public boolean getValue(){
            return true;
        }

    };
}
```

Basically instead of calling join() to end a thread I want a way to get a thread to do something and return some data to the main method while still running.

Comment: Talk about -"but it doesn't work."

Comment: calling `join()` doesn't end a thread, it allows the caller to wait till the thread being joined "ends"

Comment: A thread can't _return_ anything.  What it _can_ do is it can update some object that is visible to other threads.  The simplest way to share something between threads is to use a global (i.e., `static`) variable.  [Note:  `static` will cause you pain if you use it in a large software system, but it saves time in small, throwaway programs.]  One type of object that is very useful to share between threads is a `Queue`:  (One thread, called the "producer", puts results into the queue, and the other thread, the "consumer", takes them out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to figure out what you mean by "it doesn't work" but I think you might just missing a call to

```
threads[i].start();
```

If however you want to be able to call the getValue() method from outside of the class then you will need to create a new MyThread class which extends Thread and use that type instead of thread:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int j=0 ; j< 10; j++) {
            System.out.println("working:" + j + ":" + this.getValue());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //CODE I TRIED TO ADD:
    public boolean getValue(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then call it as follows:

```
int myNumThreads = 10;

MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[myNumThreads];
for (int i=0; i<myNumThreads; i++) {
    threads[i] = new MyThread () ;
    threads[i].start();
}
System.out.println(threads[0].getValue());
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm trying now.

Answer (score 3):

When you run code, it always uses the current thread.  If the code is attached to another thread object, e.g. Thread.join(); it is still the current thread which waits while the background thread runs.

The simplest way to get another thread to do work is to use an ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(myNumThreads);

List<Future<ResultType>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < myNumThreads; i++) {
    futures.add(es.submit(new Callable<Result>() {
        public ResultType call() {
            // do something
            return result;
        }
    });
}
// do something while the thread task executes
for (Future<ResultType> future: futures) {
    ResultType result = future.get();
}
// when finished with the pool
es.shutdown();
```

Comment: good answer! I belive the method is called `newFixedThreadPool` - not `newFixedSizePool`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write your own Thread: Like "MyThread extends Thread"

Comment: Trying that now, let's see how it'll turn out.

Comment: He understands my answer and is trying it so I think its okey.